# Can't add nodes in shader editor - Node list is Empty ( Blender 4.0 Factory Settings )

Tags: node-editor, shaders, shader-nodes

I can't add nodes in shader editor. It works for other menus.
This is a fresh blender 4.0 stable install with factory settings. Any ideas ? Thank you

[image]

Comment: No guarantee of being useful.. but my instinct would be to run Blender from the console, try this operation, and see if anything comes up.

Comment: @RobinBetts will try that as soon as I get home. Thank you.

Comment: If you start typing, you should be able to see results for the nodes you're searching for