# Blender shading node won't show any nodes in the search

Tags: shaders

In the shading tab when you want to add a color ramp or a noise texture or any node per se, you press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then you can search up the nodes. Well I just downloaded Blender 4.0.2 and when I search in the shader editor I see nothing, actually there are no nodes in the shading tab.

I did add a new material and started searching with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> for a noise texture or a color ramp or any BSDF shader and nothing, just an empty search, it only shows some materials I have from the asset library.

Comment: There have been a couple of comments about this recently, one [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304871/cant-add-nodes-in-shader-editor-node-list-is-empty-blender-4-0-factory-sett) and one on [BlenderArtists](https://blenderartists.org/t/shader-nodes-missing-in-blender-4-0/1493325) which might help.